# Do units receive a defensive bonus when you select "Do nothing" or hit space?

Tags: civilization-5

Units get a defensive bonus when you put them in "Fortify" or "Alert". But sometimes I just want to pass them over for a single turn. If I select "Do nothing" (or hit space, which is the same thing) do they still receive the defensive bonus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No they don't, this unit simply didn't take a turn - with the exception that the unit is stationed on a tile that provides a defensive bonus (for example a [fortress](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Fortress_(Civ5))) or they're on rough terrain.

A full list of conditions and bonuses as well as base statistics for each unit type is detailed in [this article](http://well-of-souls.com/civ/civ5_units.html). Of particular note is the following;

- +25% defensive bonus for rough terrain (hills, forest or jungle)
- -10% defensive penalty for open terrain (not hill, forest or jungle)
- +20-40% defensive bonus for unit Fortification. The fortifying unit gains +20% on the first turn, and +40% thereafter

Comment: Considering that fortification is a stacking bonus which increases over times (ie: 20% the unit you fortify and 40% thereafter) I very much doubt that this bonus is applied automatically for skipping turns. The only bonus I can think you'd get for skipping turns is if you're in a fortress or on a hill.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't auto-fortify if you skip turns in Civ5.

Comment: This turned out to be harder to test than I thought, since Civ 5 doesn't make it obvious what your fortify bonus is.  But using Firetuner, it appears that you are right.  A unit that selected Do Nothing the previous turn still returns 0 for GetFortifyTurns.

Comment: Is this still the case for BNW? The fortification system works differently that civ 5 vanilla with regards to cities at least, so I am curious if this changed as well